# Dynamic Memory allocation and structures

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-allocation

So i'm learning structures and am trying inputting a string with dynamic memory allocation.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  typedef struct{
    char foo[81]; 
  } TYPE;


 void function(TYPE get[]){
   char a[81];
   scanf("%s", a);

   get->foo = malloc(strlen(a)+1*sizeof(char)); //this line produces an error that it is not assignable

   strcpy(get->foo,a);

   return; 

 }
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with that statement, any help would be well appreciated.

Comment: By the way, your `malloc()` argument doesn't make any sense. You mean `(strlen(a) + 1) * sizeof (char)`, but since `sizeof (char)` is *always* 1, this should just be written as `strlen(a) + 1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`foo` is an array object and not a pointer so you can not use the operation

`get->foo = (char*)calloc(strlen(a)+1,sizeof(char));`

you are trying to assign a `(void *)` to type `char[81]`, which is totally incompatible. Lvalue should be pointer in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You have to declare you `foo` to be a char pointer.

```
typedef struct{
    char * foo; 
} TYPE;
```

Comment: Why does it not work as an array? To my (limited) understanding the pointer notation is just another way of writing an array

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to allocate memory for `foo` and assign it the address of the allocated memory. That won't work.  `foo` is an array, and has already memory allocated to it (81 `char` elements.)  And because it's an array, you can't assign an address to it.

What you want is to copy the `a` string to `foo`:

```
scanf("%s", a);
strcpy(get->foo, a);
```

However, you can do better by actually limiting the scan and copy operations to 81 characters, so that you won't write past the end of `foo` nor `a`:

```
fgets(a, 81, stdin);
strncpy(get->foo, a, 81);
```

Consulting the docs for [fgets()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [strncpy()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) is a good idea (there you can find out why you can specify 81 instead of 80 in the call to fgets().) You should always be careful not to write past the end of an array.